# Auth::check return false in middleware with Laravel-10

Tags: laravel, middleware, laravel-10

I read 25 Stackoverflow questions, solutions, and some blogs, also watch some Youtube videos on this problem. But I did not get a solution for this problem. I tried this so many times. Expecting someone's help.

**Auth file**

```
'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'web',
    // 'guard' => 'Registrationform',
    'passwords' => 'users'
],

   'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
    'Registrationform' => [
        // 'redirectTo'=> 'index',
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'Registrationforms',
       ],
],
   'providers' => [
     'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\User::class,
    ],
    'Registrationforms' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\Registrationform::class,
    ],'
```

**controller file**

```
    public function login(){
    // if(Auth::guard('Registrationform')->user()){
    //     return redirect()->route('dashboard');
    // }
    return view('login');
    }

    public function authenticate(Request $request):RedirectResponse{
      $request->validate([
        'email' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required',
    ]);

    // // $email = Request::input('email');
    // // $password = Hash::make(Request::input('password'));
     $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');
    // // dd($credentials);
    // // $credentials = $request->only(['email','password']);
    // if (aith()->attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $normal])){
    //     $remember=!empty($request->remember)? true : false;
    // if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->email,'password' =>$request- 
       >password],$remember)) {

        //dd($credentials);
        //dd(Auth::user());

       //dd(Auth::attempt($credentials));
       if(Auth::guard('Registrationform')->attempt($credentials)){
      // if(DB::raw){
        //    dump("This block is working");
        // dd("wow");
        // dd(Auth::guard('Registrationform')->login($credentials));
        // if (Auth::login($credentials))
        // {
            $request->session()->regenerate();
            $request->session()->put('user',$credentials['email']);
            return redirect()->intended('index');
        }
        // $request->session()->regenerate();
        // return redirect()->intended(route('index'));

        //call e asen bujay

        // return "hello";
    //   }
    // $user = Registrationform::where('email','=',$request->email)->first();
    // if($user && $request->password == $user->password){
    //             // return redirect()->route('index')->withSuccess('You have 
    Successfully loggedin');
    // //   Auth::login($user);
    // //   if(Auth::check()) {
    //     }

    return redirect()->route("login")->withSuccess('Oppes! You have entered invalid 
   credentials'); }

    public function index():View {
    //return View('index')->withSuccess('You have successfully logged in!');
    // dd(Auth::guard('Registrationform')->user());
    dd(Auth::guard('Registrationform')->check());
    //dd($this->guard()->check());
    // {
    //   dd("wow");
    // return view('index');
        // return redirect()->route(("index"))->withSuccess('You have successfully 
  logged in!');

    // }

    // return redirect()->route('login');  }
```

**middleware file**

```
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response{
     dd(\Auth::guard('Registrationform')->check());
    // dd($this->guard()->check());
    // $path=$request->path();
    // // // // dd( Session::get('user'));
    // if(($path=="login"||$path=="register"||$path=="index"||path=="dashboard") && 
    Session::get('user'))
    //  {
    // //   dd("wow");
    // //   return view('index');
    // //  return $next($request);
    //     //  return redirect()->route("index")->withSuccess('You have successfully 
    logged in!');
    //     //  return View("index")->withSuccess('You have successfully logged in!');
    //     return $next($request);

    //  }
    //  elseif(($path=="login"||$path !="register"||$path=="index"||$path=="dashboard") 
    && !Session::get('user')){

    //      return redirect()->route('login');
    //     }

    //     return $next($request); 
    }}
```

**Model**

```
    class RegistrationForm extends Authenticatable{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;
    protected $table = 'registrationforms';
    protected $guard = 'Registrationform';
    protected $primarykey = 'User_ID';
    protected $fillable = 
    ['First_Name','Last_Name','email','email_confirmation','password',
    'password_confirmation','Gender','birthday_day','birthday_month',
    'birthday_month','birthday_year','UserName'];
     // public $timestamps = false;


     protected $hidden = [
    'password','password_confirmation'
     ];}
```

**route**

```
    Route::post('/register', [Registrationcontroller::class,'store']);
    Route::post('/authenticate', [Registrationcontroller::class, 'authenticate']);
    Route::middleware(registrationform::class)->group(function(){
    Route::get('/login',[Registrationcontroller::class, 'login'])->name('login');
    Route::get('/register', [Registrationcontroller::class,'register'])- 
    >name('register');
    Route::get('/index', [Registrationcontroller::class,'index'])->name('index');
    Route::get('/dashboard', [Registrationcontroller::class,'dashboard'])- 
    >name('dashboard');});
    Route::post("/logout",[Registrationcontroller::class,'logout'])->name("logout");
```

**kernel**

```
     protected $middleware = [
    // \App\Http\Middleware\TrustHosts::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
    \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\HandleCors::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
    ];

     /**
    * The application's route middleware groups.
    *
    * @var array<string, array<int, class-string|string>>
    */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,

        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

       'api' => [
        // \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class.':api',
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
        ];

        /**
        * The application's middleware aliases.
         *
         * Aliases may be used instead of class names to conveniently assign middleware 
          to routes and groups.
          *
         * @var array<string, class-string|string>
          */
    protected $middlewareAliases = [
    'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'auth.session' => \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
    'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
    'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'password.confirm' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\RequirePassword::class,
    'signed' => \App\Http\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
    'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
    'Registrationform' => \App\Http\Middleware\registrationform::class,
];
```

**Note-1:**  **StartSession::class**, transferred to  **protected $middleware** from  **protected $middlewareGroups WEB**.Have any queries just comment me.

**Note-02:** I used **use Auth** instead of **Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth**.

**Note-3:** If you want to join anydesk you can.

**Take Advance Thanks.**

Answer (score 1):

you can add `$primaryKey = 'user_id'` in User models, hope can help you

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to understand your code but I think it boils down to this:

Middleware is ran before your controller code. So the order of code is:

1. Middleware (your auth check)
2. Controller (your login action)
3. Blade

So whenever you log the user in, the middleware is called, before your user is actually logged in by the controller. So `Auth::check` fails, because the login has not been executed yet.

Comment: But If I use auth::check in controller same occurrence happen without middleware.

Answer (score 0):

I found out about your problem, declare it in user.php

```
protected $primaryKey = 'user_id';
protected $keyType = 'string';
public $incrementing = false;
```

by default, the primary key will always be the id. If you declare a different column name that will serve as your primary key, don't forget to declare the codes that I stated above or else you end not reading the auth or not logging in.